# Is a good idea reference a primary key using pivot table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a Laravel application right now and this doubt came to me. The proccess is: one customer make one or many **requests** of some **products**, then, I can offer one or many **deals**, based in their product requests.

I created the Product, Request and Deal Laravel models but I need to connect them. I set a many-to-many relationship with Product and Request models through *belongsToMany* method. My problem is how to set a relationship between Deal and the request. As I said, one deal can contain many request of a product or products.

The structures and relationships of the tables are:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this creating a new model called RequestedProduct referred to "products_requests" table. Also, I dropped the primary key and add an Id attribute to this one.

Also, I need that the composite index (request_id, product_id) doesn't repeat in a row so, i created an unique index.